# How to move pairs of columns to new table, saving FK to the old table and creating a new column with a value as a name of column?

Tags: postgresql

I downloaded database with translations of countries and cities to 70 languages (some of translations are ''), but translations and technical information (populations, flags, territory, phones, etc) about cities\countries saved in the same table.

I mean every translation has its own columns (tranlation itself + description on the language of translation) next to the other info which is not related to translation. Totally about 190 colums, including 70*2 (translation + description).

I don't think this is proper way and I want to move all translations to seperated table keeping FK to main\technical-info table.

So, now I have a table "cities" with the structure like below:

```
id region_id countries_id phone population lang_1 description_1 lang_2  description_2 lang_3  description_3 .... lang_70       description_70
1      1           1       +7       123    Москва  SomeDesc     Moscow  SomeDesc2     Moskwa  SomeText3          Translation70 SomeDesc70
2      1           1       +7       123    Кубинка SomeDesc     Kubinka SomeDesc2     Kubinka    ''              Translation70 SomeDesc70
```

with 2.5M rows\cities.

I want to move all "lang_(1-70)" and their descriptions to new table "cities_translated" which should look like that:

```
id cities_id name          description lang
1     1      Москва        SomeDesc    lang_1
2     1      Moscow        SomeDesc2   lang_2
3     1      Moskwa        SomeText3   lang_3
...
70    1      Translation70 SomeDesc70  lang_70
71    2      Кубинка       SomeDesc    lang_1
72    2      Kubinka       SomeDesc2   lang_2
73    2      Kubinka       SomeDesc3   lang_3
...
140   2      Translation70 SomeDesc70  lang_70
```

Could anyone help me please with proper query to do this transfer?

P.S. I have already a table "languages" and as the next step I will replace all values like 'lang_1', 'lang_2' and so on to proper FK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoped to get raw sql solution in order to improve my sql knowledge, but due to no anwers, i decided to use Python.

```
initial_table = 'countries.city'
init_table_columns = ['lang_1', 'description_1', 'lang_2', 'description_2', 'lang_3', 'description_3', 'lang_4', 'description_4', 'lang_5', 'description_5', 'lang_6', 'description_6', 'lang_7', 'description_7', 'lang_8', 'description_8', 'lang_9', 'description_9', 'lang_10', 'description_10', 'lang_11', 'description_11', 'lang_12', 'description_12', 'lang_13', 'description_13', 'lang_14', 'description_14', 'lang_15', 'description_15', 'lang_16', 'description_16', 'lang_17', 'description_17', 'lang_18', 'description_18', 'lang_19', 'description_19', 'lang_20', 'description_20', 'lang_21', 'description_21', 'lang_22', 'description_22', 'lang_23', 'description_23', 'lang_24', 'description_24', 'lang_25', 'description_25', 'lang_26', 'description_26', 'lang_27', 'description_27', 'lang_28', 'description_28', 'lang_29', 'description_29', 'lang_30', 'description_30', 'lang_31', 'description_31', 'lang_32', 'description_32', 'lang_33', 'description_33', 'lang_34', 'description_34', 'lang_35', 'description_35', 'lang_36', 'description_36', 'lang_37', 'description_37', 'lang_38', 'description_38', 'lang_39', 'description_39', 'lang_40', 'description_40', 'lang_41', 'description_41', 'lang_42', 'description_42', 'lang_43', 'description_43', 'lang_44', 'description_44', 'lang_45', 'description_45', 'lang_46', 'description_46', 'lang_47', 'description_47', 'lang_48', 'description_48', 'lang_49', 'description_49', 'lang_50', 'description_50', 'lang_51', 'description_51', 'lang_52', 'description_52', 'lang_53', 'description_53', 'lang_54', 'description_54', 'lang_55', 'description_55', 'lang_56', 'description_56', 'lang_57', 'description_57', 'lang_58', 'description_58', 'lang_59', 'description_59', 'lang_60', 'description_60', 'lang_61', 'description_61', 'lang_62', 'description_62', 'lang_63', 'description_63', 'lang_64', 'description_64', 'lang_65', 'description_65', 'lang_66', 'description_66', 'lang_67', 'description_67', 'lang_68', 'description_68', 'lang_69', 'description_69', 'lang_70', 'description_70']

table_translation = 'countries.city_translated'

import psycopg2
import re

conn = psycopg2.connect(database="countries", host='localhost', user="postgres", password="Password")
cur = conn.cursor()
new_cursor = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("""SELECT id FROM %s """ % initial_table)
rows = cur.fetchall()
print("%i rows retrieved" % cur.rowcount)

new_cursor.execute("""BEGIN""")

for row in rows:
    print('row:', row)
    get_id = row[0]
    cur.execute("""SELECT %s FROM %s WHERE id=%s """ % (",".join(init_table_columns), initial_table, get_id))
    row_w_info = cur.fetchall()
    for i in range(140):
        if i%2==0:
            name = row_w_info[0][i]
            description = row_w_info[0][i+1]

            lang_text = init_table_columns[i]
            lang_id = int(re.findall(r'\d+', lang_text)[0])

            # There are 70 translations, but there is no info what languages are 68, 69, 70
            if lang_id >= 68:
                lang_id = None

            new_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO countries.city_translated (city_id, name, description, lang_id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)", (get_id, name, description, lang_id))

new_cursor.execute("""COMMIT""")

cur.close()
new_cursor.close()
conn.close()
```